# How to replace couchbase document using CAS - couchbase node js 2.0

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have CAS Id which I got from querying document by get() method.
Now I want to update the same document only if its CAS value is not changed.

So for that I need to provide CAS in replace() method but I don't know how to do it.

Please help me if anybody knows how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using API docs at http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.0.0/Bucket.html#replace you can do it like this:

```
var myCas = ...;
var myBucket = myCluster.openBucket();
myBucket.replace('document_name', {some: 'value'}, {cas: myCas},
  function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('operation failed', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('success!', res);
  });
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to get the CAS value in node. I am getting following error while running the above code
    [TypeError: cas option needs to be a CAS object.]